# How do I specify the type of a map used with a template?

Tags: c++

I first have this simple example that works (my first time using maps). The type of the name-value pairs is a string to a function pointer respectively.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using std::cout;

int foo() {
    return 243;
}

int main() {

    std::map<std::string, int (*)()> list;

    list["a"] = foo;

    cout << list["a"](); // 243

}
```

Then I tried using a template to specify the type. Where it says `int` in the map instantiation is where I'd like to specify the type using a template. So I tried but I don't exactly know where to put `<int>` where I'm either calling the function or making the name-value pairs. This is what I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using std::cout;

int foo() {
    return 243;
}

int main() {

    template <typename N>
    std::map<std::string, N (*)()> list;

    list["A"] = <int> foo; // right here where you see <int>

    cout << list["A"]();

}
```

This doesn't work because I don't think I'm putting `<int>` in the right place. The errors I'm getting are:

```
/tmp/134535385811595.cpp: In function 'int main()':
/tmp/134535385811595.cpp:11: error: expected primary-expression before 'template'
/tmp/134535385811595.cpp:11: error: expected `;' before 'template'
/tmp/134535385811595.cpp:14: error: 'list' was not declared in this scope
/tmp/134535385811595.cpp:14: error: expected primary-expression before '<' token
/tmp/134535385811595.cpp:14: error: 'N' was not declared in this scope
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve? This code is so confused that I can't imagine what you were trying to do...

Comment: What do you want to get at the end?

Comment: You're trying to use a template in a non-template function.

Comment: The first example works. I have a map that uses a string like `list["A"]` and then an integer returing function pointer that points to whatever function you supply `list["A"]` (i.e`list["A"] = foo`). That works  because foo is a function that returns an integer. Now I'm just trying to specify that it's an integer pointer I want to use.

Comment: @David: Your first example works... we can see that. Now what is a motivating example of the effect that you are trying to achieve with the second example that you can't get with the first?

Comment: @Mankarse It's just practice. I just wanted it to do the same as the first example only me using a template to specify the return type of the function pointer instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <typename N>
std::map<std::string, N (*)()> list;
```

`template<typename>` syntax is used for definitions of templates. Map class template is already defined elsewhere, you can only provide template parameters when you're instantiating it.

You can do what you want by wrapping your map in a class template:

```
template<typename ReturnType>
struct Wrapper {
    std::map<std::string, ReturnType (*)()> m;
};
```

and then instantiate and use it like:

```
int foo() { }

Wrapper<int> w;
w.m["foo"] = foo;
```